# OpenLaszlo scrolling issue

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I am having a view like mentioned below and i am adding lot of views dynamically to the contents view and the problem is scrollbar is not getting visible. So i drilled down aa bit and i found that the content's height is not getting updated after i have added the views dynamically.

What am i doing wrong here? The same code is working properly in Openlaszlo 3.3

```
<view name="wrapper">
 <view name="scrollablecontainer"
                  width="${this.contentwrapper.width &gt; parent.width
                         ? this.contentwrapper.width : parent.width}"
                  height="${this.contentwrapper.height &gt; parent.height 
                          ? this.contentwrapper.height : parent.height}">
                <view name="contentwrapper" >
                    <view name="contents"/>
                </view>
  </view>
 <vscrollbarnew name="vscroll"
                        height="${this.height}"
                        pagesize="${this.height}"
                        visible="${this.scrollable}"/>
</view>
```

I missed out one thing when the component initializes i am setting  contentwrapper width and height to 0.

Runtime : swf
Test browser: firefox, windows xp

Answer (score 1):

Your structure looks very complicated. Why do you have a contentwrapper and a contents view. I've created an example which compiles in both OpenLaszlo 3.4 (swf7 and swf8) and OpenLaszlo 5.0 trunk (SWF10 and DHTML). I've set clipping to true on the `wrapper` view and added a layout to the view `scrollablecontainer` into which the dynamically created views will be added.

```
<canvas height="400">

    <attribute name="counter" type="number" value="0" />

    <class name="rectangle" width="200" height="30" bgcolor="blue">
        <text name="label" align="center" valign="middle" />
    </class>

    <!-- Wrapping view needs to have a width and height set and clip set to true -->
    <view name="wrapper" x="100" y="10"
          width="236" height="150"
          bgcolor="#ff9999"
          clip="true">

        <view x="10" name="scrollablecontainer"
              bgcolor="#aaaaaa">

            <simplelayout axis="y" spacing="8" />

        </view>

        <vscrollbar name="vscroll"
                    visible="${this.scrollable}"/>
    </view>

    <method name="addView">
        var v = null;
        if ( $swf7 || $swf8 ) {
            v = new rectangle( canvas.wrapper.scrollablecontainer );
        } else {
            v = new lz.rectangle( canvas.wrapper.scrollablecontainer );
        }
        canvas.counter++;
        v.label.setAttribute( 'text', 'View #' + canvas.counter );
    </method>

    <view>
        <checkbox value="true" onvalue="canvas.wrapper.setAttribute('clip', this.value)" />
        <text x="20" >Clipping of view 'wrapper'</text>
    </view>

    <button y="25" text="Add view" onclick="canvas.addView()" />

</canvas>
```

The view named `wrapper` should have clipping enabled, and needs to have a value set for width and height. By clicking the checkbox you can toggle the value of the `clip` attribute for the wrapper to see the effect.

Here's the app running in OpenLaszlo 5.0 trunk SWF10:
[image: OpenLaszlo scrollbar and dynamic view generation]

And here the same code running in OpenLaszlo 3.4 SWF8:
[image]